# Is it OK to delete window from callback window function (Windows OS)?

Tags: windows

I want to make Application where you can see only one window at a time in order to save memory. Let's say, we have one window, after pressing a button another window shows, but the previous is deleted. If the button pressing is handled in window callback function, is it safe to delete the window from inside of that window function and recreate it after the new window is closed? Something like that:

```
void callback(...) {
...
if (msgID == ENTER_KEY) {
  deleteMyself();
  showWindow2();
  createMyself();
}
...
}
```

Could you suggest better approach if this one is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is generally on a desktop a bad idea. So you would loose everything the userinput. And depending on your application the user maybe confuses why an options dialog closes the main window.

However on a mobile device it is normal only to have just one window (except you use dialogs). But in those cases all inputs should be stored so that the window can be reovered to its old state.

In general if you have trouble with the memory managment better check if you leak somewhere memory in most cases the GUI does not need so much memory.

Comment: what I am afraid of is will the approach above lead to exceptions because the rest of code (or OS code) points to the old window which was deleted?

Comment: That depends on your code. If you correctly add all handlers and removes them if they are not needed you should not have any problems. You code above looks like C++ but I'm not sure if this is native WinAPI or MFC or some other gui toolkit. So I cannot say what you should care about.